# Dual booting Ubuntu help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, 22.04

When trying to dual boot Ubuntu on my laptop the screen keeps going black every 10-30 seconds. It is not shutting off, when I press the keyboard keys multiple times, the screen turns on (but does not work when I click on the mouse). This occurs whilst trying to install Ubuntu. I did manage to install Ubuntu on my laptop while it kept turning off, but the same issue kept occurring and it seems the issue is that the laptop is locking itself.

I have disabled Secure Boot, and also disabled auto lock, however the screen still turns black and then turns on the home page. I have also tried to install multiple versions like 20.04 and 22.04.

System details:

- Samsung Galaxy Book 2
- Intel Iris graphics card
- 12th gen intel(R) core i5 processor (1.3GHz)
- 8 GB of RAM
  -Dual boot with Windows 11

If anyone could help me resolve this issue I would be grateful!

Comment: May be similar? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2483059

Comment: hello, my laptop turns off very often to the point it is practically unusable so I doubt this is the same issue.

Comment: Try the Ubuntu 23.10 with the 6.5 kernel.

Comment: @ubfan1 i have tried this and the same issue occurs

Comment: Take a look at the Setting/Power settings.  e.g. you can set screen blank to "never" and "dim" to 5 min.

Comment: @ubfan1 also tried this and the screen still turns black every 10 seconds or so

Answer (score 0):

So i have finally figured out how to fix this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

Once i had enabled the windows subsystem for linux and then enabled the virtual machine feature,I had to restart my laptop and accidentally booted into ubuntu instead of windows and ubuntu started working! honestly not sure what this does but it has worked for now!